# Are there limited traffic zones in Santiago de Chile?

Tags: driving, santiago-de-chile

Mid-March I will stay in Santiago for 5 days. I've booked a rental car. During my stay I will travel along Viña del Mar, Rancagua and Valparaíso, but the precise dates for each stay aren't fixed yet. So I think I'll stay in Santiago about 2 days.

I come from Italy and in big cities I'm used to limited traffic zones and I'm wondering if in Santiago there are parts of the center that may be restricted (it would be frustrating to find out a lot of bills once I leave the city), and if so, I'm looking for a site where I can find a map where those restricted zones are signaled. I've searched on the net but yet I found no site about it.

Comment: I believe you could find some here, but in spanish -> http://www.uoct.cl/restriccion-vehicular/

Comment: @MarcelP. care to add an answer?

Comment: I am not an expert in Chile, I only have used my knowledge in spanish to find it. Maybe, some from Chile or Santiago could help.

Comment: At this point @ana.luis has probably returned from her trip. I wonder if she can answer this question herself.

Comment: By "limited traffic zones," do you mean the same thing as [congestion charge zones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Congestion_pricing), like in London and Stockholm? I've never heard the term "limited traffic zones" used to describe them.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there were some zones including the center and the very close avenues, but there were little signaling, all I saw were some id cards on cars dashboard. To avoid this misconfusing problem I choosed to go by walk and use metro.